# Information about series sum function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I used an [online tool](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/series-calculator/) that solves symbolic series sums and gives a breakdown of the steps. One of the steps that it gave was:

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^k}{k+t+1}
> $$
> is a known series. It is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z_0^k(k+r_0)^{-n_0} = \Phi(z_0,n_0,r_0)$ for $z_0=1-p, n_0=1, r_0=t+1$.

I am unfamiliar with this $\Phi(z_0,n_0,r_0)$ - I am looking for information about it, in particular any lower and upper bounds that would be useful in deriving simpler bounds for my problem.

Comment: What are your conditions for $p$  ? Have a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.01122.pdf

Comment: $p$ is actually a probability so $z < 1$. I actually do know that the series converges. Overall my final result (of which $\Phi$ was part) is $1 - p(t+1)\Phi(1-p, 1, t+1)$ where $t$ is an integer. In my case $p=\frac{n}{t+1}$ for a fixed integer, $n$, so the above becomes $1 - n\Phi(1 - \frac{n}{t+1}, 1, t+1)$. $t \geq n$ is also an integer.

Comment: Let $t=k n$ and, for a fixed value of $k$, plot the function vs $n$. They look like hyperboles.

Comment: I've added a follow-up question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955956/lower-bounds-for-larch-transendant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^k}{k+t+1}=\Phi (1-p,1,t+1)$$ which is  the [Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function).

Have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/search/search?q=Lerch%20transcendent) for more information.