# Lower bounds for Lerch transendant

Tags: special-functions, upper-lower-bounds

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955880/information-about-series-sum-function). My overall expression is:
$$
1 - n\Phi(1 - \frac{n}{t+1},1,t+1)
$$
for fixed integer $n$, and for integer $t \in [n,N]$.
I'm looking for an upper bound on the above expression.

Comment: Did you mean "Lerch"?

Comment: Fixed - thanks.